# How to get rid of annoying overlay icons for desktop icons? (picure included)

Tags: windows, icons, desktop

How to get rid of annoying overlay icons for desktop icons? The three main ones I noticed were the blue on white curved up arrow, the shield icon, and the two blue arrows hitting eachother. I know that sounds confusing so I added screenshots. Please let me know if you have a fix for this.

[image: img] [image: img] [image: img]

Comment: The shield means the shortcut is set to always launch as administrator and will give a UAC prompt. Disabling launch as admin will remove that shield. The 2 blue arrow icons means the shortcut is compressed. Rightclick the shortcut, properties, advanced, and uncheck compress. The curved arrow on white means it is a shortcut and requires a hack to remove it.

Comment: @LPChip Arrows does not appear when checking or unchecking "compressed" size of the link is not changing too, partly your comment seems to be false.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer compressing is a feature of the NTFS filesystem and GPO may deny it. Just because it doesn't work for you does it invalidate my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to download and install the
[Winaero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/winaero-tweaker/).

Run it and go to *Appearance > Shortcut Arrow*, where you may choose
"No arrow".

For more information see
[Remove shortcut arrow overlay in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/remove-shortcut-arrow-overlay-in-windows-10/).

---

Addition by user @LPChip:

The shield means the shortcut is set to always launch as administrator and will give a UAC prompt. Disabling launch as admin will remove that shield.

The 2 blue arrow icons means the shortcut is compressed.
Right-click the shortcut, Properties, Advanced, and uncheck
Compress.

The curved arrow on white means it is a shortcut and requires
the above hack to remove it.

Comment: Wouldn't this remove the icon overley everywhere, not just the desktop?

Comment: @LPChip: You're right. I'll rewrite the answer.

Comment: Great. Given that your answer only solves 1 of the 3 problems, and my comment on the question solves the other two, mind adding my comment to your answer? I don't want to edit your answer and add it as I feel that is vandalism. :)

Comment: @LPChip: Done as you asked. In general I'm not against people improving my answers.

Comment: I think this way is better. :) +1 for the answer as it is now. :)